# Running a war in a Elastic Beanstalk Java environment (not tomcat)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jsp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war

I have an app that uses spring boot to bootstrap an embedded tomcat 7 which serves jsp files.
In /WEB-INF I have all the jps files and, for this reason, I have to package my app as a war file.

For some unknown reason, if I run the app with "java -jar app.war", it works OK.
But if I rename app.war to app.jar and run the app with "java -jar app.jar", this won't work and the servlet throws an error because it can't find some files located under /WEB-INF.

So, in order to run my app in Elastic Beanstalk, I'd need to run my app ending in .war. However, EB renames my .war to .jar every time I deploy a new version and runs it with java -jar application.jar, which won't work.
How can I change this behavior?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Why didnot you build your file in .jar file? Because you use embbeded tomcat so you can build jar file instead of war file

Comment: Because I have a bunch of jsp files that the embedded tomcat searchs for under /WEB-INF and if I don't pack my app as a war, they're not included in the final bundle. I'm open to suggestions if you know a way to make tomcat work together with jsp files in a jar.

Comment: Yes, I often use embbeded tomcat with jar bundle. I found very simple sample on this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

Comment: How would you do it with spring boot as the main application loader?

Comment: Do you mean main class for Springboot?  like this? `@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;`

Comment: Thanks @BTuan. I found another way: moving /WEB-INF under src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/
This links explains it very well: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1
Thank you for your time!!